# Excel VBA Range RandBetween function returns an error

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to random between an excel range and get a non-duplicated result.

I get a cell value when I type `Msgbox Range("C2")`.

However, when I use `MsgBox Range("F" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, UBound(ElementHeader)))`, it tells me `'type-mismatch'`.

Any idea why? And how do I actually store it into a String array in VBA?

My code looks like this:

```
Sub Testy()
    Dim ElementHeader
    ElementHeader = Range("F1:F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    MsgBox Range("F" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, UBound(ElementHeader)))
End Sub
```

This is just part of the code, but I'm looking to store it into a array so I can check each of them to see if there are any duplicates.

```
Sub GenerateDescription()
    Dim Element
    Dim AddOn
    Dim MainRange
    ' Declare Sentences
    ' Addon Range is in Column F
    AddOn = Range("G1:G" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    ' Main Range is in Column D
    Set MainRange = Range("E1:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each Element In MainRange
            Element.Offset(, 4).Value = Element & " " & Range("G" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, UBound(AddOn))) & " " & Range("G" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, UBound(AddOn))) & " " & Range("G" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, UBound(AddOn))) & " " & Range("G" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, UBound(AddOn))) & " " & Range("G" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, UBound(AddOn)))
        Next Element
End Sub
```

As you can see, this repeated `G` Range is the part I'm trying to solve.

I want the Column G sentences to appear only once per `For Each` method. Meaning, I want each element to contain 5 unique sentences from Column G.

Let's say I have 10 sentences, and for each loop, I want to get 5 unique sentences, which for example is: G1, G4, G2, G9, G10. There should **never** be a repeat of the same cell, meaning if the function generates G1, G2, G5, G3, G1, I want to replace the duplicate G1 with another random cell number from Column G.

Comment: `Msgbox UBound(ElementHeader)` will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: ? It's still returning `type-mismatch`.

Comment: Debug and see what is in ElementHeader.

Comment: `Range("F2:F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` this counts the row...

Comment: We will probably need to see the entire code.

Comment: `Sub Testy()
ElementHeader = Range("F1:F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range("F" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, UBound(ElementHeader)))
End Sub` there you go. that's the entire function. and Column F has 3 words, A, B, C.

Comment: That code you posted does not even compile.  Are you sure its the entire code?

Comment: Yes... I already found out the problem. I didn't declare `Dim ElementHeader`.

Comment: All I need to do now is get it sorted out into a String array, then check for duplicates. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Chip Pearson's function for unique random numbers and adjust your code to something like this:

```
For Each Element In MainRange
    vRandom = UniqueRandomLongs(1, UBound(AddOn), 5)
    Element.Offset(, 4).Value = Element & " " & _
    Range("G" & vRandom(1)) & " " & _
    Range("G" & vRandom(2)) & " " & _
    Range("G" & vRandom(3)) & " " & _
    Range("G" & vRandom(4)) & " " & _
    Range("G" & vRandom(5))
Next Element
```

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RandomNumbers.aspx

```
Public Function UniqueRandomLongs(Minimum As Long, Maximum As Long, _
            Number As Long, Optional ArrayBase As Long = 1, _
            Optional Dummy As Variant) As Variant
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' UniqueRandomLongs
' This returns an array containing elements whose values are between the Minimum and
' Maximum parameters. The number of elements in the result array is specified by the
' Number parameter. For example, you can request an array of 20 Longs between 500 and
' 1000 (inclusive).
' There will be no duplicate values in the result array.
'
' The ArrayBase parameter is used to specify the LBound of the ResultArray. If this
' is omitted, ResultArray is 1-based.
'
' The Dummy argument is to be used only when the function is called from a worksheet.
' Its purpose is to allow you to use the NOW() function as the Dummy parameter to force
' Excel to calculate this function any time a calculation is performed. E.g.,
'       =UniqueRandomLongs(100,199,10,NOW())
' If you don't want to recalulate this function on every calculation, omit the Dummy
' parameter. The Dummy argument serves no other purpose and is not used anywhere
' in the code.
'
' The function returns an array of Longs if successful or NULL if an error occurred
' (invalid input parameter).
'
' Note: The procedure creates its own array of size (Maximum-Minium+1), so very large
' differences between Minimum and Maximum may cause performace issues.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim SourceArr() As Long
Dim ResultArr() As Long
Dim SourceNdx As Long
Dim ResultNdx As Long
Dim TopNdx As Long
Dim Temp As Long

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Test the input parameters to ensure
' they are valid.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If Minimum > Maximum Then
    UniqueRandomLongs = Null
    Exit Function
End If
If Number > (Maximum - Minimum + 1) Then
    UniqueRandomLongs = Null
    Exit Function
End If
If Number <= 0 Then
    UniqueRandomLongs = Null
    Exit Function
End If

Randomize
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Redim the arrays.
' SourceArr will be sized with an LBound of
' Minimum and a UBound of Maximum, and will
' contain the integers between Minimum and
' Maximum (inclusive). ResultArray gets
' a LBound of ArrayBase and a UBound of
' (ArrayBase+Number-1)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
ReDim SourceArr(Minimum To Maximum)
ReDim ResultArr(ArrayBase To (ArrayBase + Number - 1))
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Load SourceArr with the integers between
' Minimum and Maximum (inclusive).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
For SourceNdx = Minimum To Maximum
    SourceArr(SourceNdx) = SourceNdx
Next SourceNdx

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' TopNdx is the upper limit of the SourceArr
' from which the Longs will be selected. It
' is initialized to UBound(SourceArr), and
' decremented in each iteration of the loop.
' Selections from SourceArr are always in the
' region including and to the left of TopNdx.
' The region above (to the right of) TopNdx
' is where the used numbers are stored and
' no selection is made from that region of
' the array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
TopNdx = UBound(SourceArr)
For ResultNdx = LBound(ResultArr) To UBound(ResultArr)
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Set SourceNdx to a random number between 1 and
    ' TopNdx. ResultArr(ResultNdx) will get its value from
    ' SourceArr(SourceNdx). Only elements of SourceArr
    ' in the region of the array below (to the left of)
    ' TopNdx (inclusive) will be selected for inclusion
    ' in ResultArr. This ensures that the elements in
    ' ResultArr are not duplicated.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    SourceNdx = Int((TopNdx - Minimum + 1) * Rnd + Minimum)
    ResultArr(ResultNdx) = SourceArr(SourceNdx)
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Now, swap elements SourceNdx and TopNdx of SourceArr,
    ' moving the value in SourceArr(SourceNdx) to the region
    ' of SourceArr that is above TopNdx.  Since only elements
    ' of SourceArr in the region below TopNdx (inclusive) are
    ' possible candidates for inclusion in ResultArr, used
    ' values are placed at TopNdx to ensure no duplicates.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Temp = SourceArr(SourceNdx)
    SourceArr(SourceNdx) = SourceArr(TopNdx)
    SourceArr(TopNdx) = Temp
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Decrment TopNdx. This moves the effective UBound of SourceArr
    ' downwards (to the left), thus removing used numbers from the
    ' possibility of inclusion in ResultArr. This ensures we have
    ' no duplicates in the ResultArr.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    TopNdx = TopNdx - 1
Next ResultNdx

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Return the result array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
UniqueRandomLongs = ResultArr

End Function
```

Comment: I'm looking for a checking algorithm for the code itself, because I'll be getting ElementHeader's Range twice and I don't want a duplicate of A or B or C in Column F. Meaning it should either display A, B or A, C or B, C.

Comment: @Reno Sorry, I want to help but I just don't understand what you are asking.  You need to re-write your question more clearly.  Perhaps with sample data and expected results.

Comment: whoa, wow, this will take quite some time to digest... thanks for helping me out, I'll try what you gave and see if it works!

Comment: Don't worry to much about the function, it simply returns an array of (as many as you require) random numbers between the minimum and maximum you specify.